# Using Asp.net Identity with service instead of dbcontext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, wcf, asp.net-identity, multi-tier

I have a multi-tier application with real physical tiers in different servers, I want to use asp.net Identity for my Authorization. But I wonder if it is possible that, Identity uses my DAL Service for db jobs, because I don't have any access to dbcontext directly from my UI or Business tiers. so to use Identity I need to use my DAL Service.

Comment: You need to implement your own `IUserStore` and `IRoleStore`. See here for ideas: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/01/20/implementing-asp-net-identity.aspx and http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity